# How to generate @XmlSchemaType for an element customized with xjc:javaType

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I would like to use xjc to generate JAXB objects while using an XmlJavaTypeAdapter

I'm currently using the following in global bindings:

```
<xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean" 
                      xmlType="xsd:boolean" 
                      adapter="path.to.my.CustomBooleanAdapter"/>
```

It generates the following code:

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomBooleanAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(type=String.class)
    private Boolean finished;
```

However I would like the code to have the @XmlSchemaType of boolean and without the @XmlElement type String

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "boolean")
private Boolean finished;
```

Adapter code:

```
public class CustomBooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(String s) {
        if("true".equals(s) || "false".equals(s)){
            return Boolean.valueOf(s);
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Boolean c) {
        return c == null ? null : c.toString();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell xjc to generate the @XmlSchemaType annotation and remove the @XmlElement of type String

Comment: Could you please also post your `CustomBooleanAdapter`?

Comment: @lexicore I've added the adapter code above, any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I think you get `String` because your adapter is `Boolean` to `String`. I think you could override the annotations with the annotate plugin, but first the question - why? Any particular reason for this? I mean, you're not likely to generate schema from your code if you use XJC...

Comment: @lexicore Thanks from the quick response. there is a plan to use a code documentation generation tool which is generating the documentation from the annotation... and based on the xjc generated code, the documentation generation tool is currently creating an xsd with type xs:string instead of xs:boolean

Comment: OK, I see. This is a valid reason. You can use the my annotate plugin to override the annotations. But I think you must not override the `@XmlElement.type` as it might be linked to the type of the marshaller. I'll make an example for you and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as promised.

The [Annotate plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) allows you to add annotations to the generated code.

SO disclaimer: I am the author.

Documentation is [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin).

[Example](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/one/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L27-L38):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox xjc"
    jaxb:version="1.0">

    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean" xmlType="xs:boolean" adapter="org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.tests.one.CustomBooleanAdapter"/>
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:complexType name="javaTypeExample">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="customBooleanProperty" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(type=java.lang.Boolean.class)</annox:annotate>
                        <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name="boolean")</annox:annotate>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Generates:

```
@XmlElement(type = Boolean.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomBooleanAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "boolean")
protected Boolean customBooleanProperty;
```

Few notes on usage:

- Note that you have to say `target="field"` since you have to put your annotations on the field, otherwise they will be added to the getter by default.
- Syntax is Java, but...
- ... you have to use fully qualified class names for everything (annotations, classes in annotation fields etc.)
- You can't delete the `@XmlElement` annotation (no such feature), but you can overwrite it with `@XmlElement(type=Boolean.class)`.

I also added a small [test case](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/one/src/test/java/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/tests/one/JavaTypeExampleTest.java).

Comment: Thanks @lexicore this looks like the solution I need, I am trying it out and will let you know the results.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore, I finally got it to work just like you explained.  (I had the wrong maven dependencies, so it took me a while to get it working)   I think the @XmlElement(type=Boolean.class) was given a class cast exception though, so not sure I can use it for this purpose afterall.  I've come across several other use cases where I wanted to add annotations to generated jaxb objects though, so this will come in handy for those purposes. Thanks so much for your suggestions and example.